# generate random -1 or 1 values in a single line of code

Tags: python

I'd like to generate random values equal to -1 or 1. I can do that by generating random integer values 0 or 1 times 2 and minus 1, but maybe there is a more simple way of doing this?

Comment: That's not very random.

Comment: [The simplest way.](http://www.xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about?

`random.choice([-1, 1])`

Example -

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice([-1, 1])
1
>>> choice([-1, 1])
-1
>>> choice([-1, 1])
1
>>> choice([-1, 1])
-1
>>> choice([-1, 1])
-1
>>> choice([-1, 1])
1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
print 1 if random.random() >= 0.5 else -1
```

Comment: This is the fastest way (although that doesn't really matter)